# How to read an Excel file in Apache nifi and give the Excel data as input to next processor?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read Excel file in Apache nifi and get the content as attribute and need to pass the attribute as input to other processor. For eg. If I am having an Excel like below
Column1 Column2
Row1 Input1.  Input2
Row2 Input1.  Input2

I need to take the values of Row1 and it should be configured to Getfile processor input directory and Gettfile processor should point to Input1 directory. All the above flows should automatically taken by reading the Excel file.
I tried reading Excel by GetFile-> ConvertExceltoCSV processor but it is giving the content but not sure how to change each row as attribute in nifi.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do it like this:

1. GetFile -> to obtain the CSV content
2. SplitRecord -> Reader=CSV, Writter=JSON
3. EvaluateJsonPath

Now we have separated rows from the CSV file.

In the `EvaluateJsonPath` you can switch the `destination` to flowfile-attribute.

And with that done, you would click on the `+` sign on the top right and write name of the property and then for the value, you would put the Header of the column...

So as in your Example the JSON would look like:

```
{
    "Column1": "[Input1]",
    "Column2": "[Input2]"
}
```

Then in the EvaluateJsonPath you would add property `Input1` with value `$.Column1` (with the `+` button)

That will put the Content of `Column1-Row1` (Your `input1`) into the flow-file attribute as

`Input1 = "whatever you have in the excel"`

Route that to GetFile processor, and you can use your attribute as `${Input1}`

Do the same for the `$.Column2` in the EvaluateJsonPath and you are ready to go

Hope that helps